# automatically sync local git repository with remote repository when there is a new commit on the same branch

Tags: git, github, webhooks

I have cloned a git repository on an amazon ec2 instance. I want to make it so that the local repository on ec2 instance always automatically syncs (perhaps using `git pull command`) when there is new commits to the same branch on the remote repository. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you using a popular service such as GitHub o BitBucket?  If so, you can use their web hooks features...GitHub: https://help.github.com/articles/about-webhooks/ and BitBucket: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/manage-webhooks-735643732.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow the steps here if you wish to keep your servers synced up to the latest changes on the branch your server is on. 'Git pull' will be made when a commit is made or when a pull request is closed.

Add this to your codebase to trigger,

```
// This function serves as the Payload URL for Github's webhook
// https://github.com/reponame/projectname/settings/hooks/
public function post_receive() 
{
    // copied from 'https://gist.github.com/1809044'
    $commands = array(
        'hostname',
        'echo $PWD',
        'whoami',
        'git fetch',
        'branch=$(git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD)',
        'git reset --hard origin/$branch',
        'git pull',
        'git status'
    );

    // Run the commands for output
    $output = '';
    foreach($commands AS $command){
        // Run it
        $tmp = shell_exec($command);
        // Output
        $output .= "<span style=\"color: #6BE234;\">\$</span> <span style=\"color: #729FCF;\">{$command}\n</span>";
        $output .= htmlentities(trim($tmp)) . PHP_EOL.'<br/>';
    }

    print_r($output);

}
```

Go to Webhooks and Services on Github.com, https://github.com/reponame/projectname/settings/hooks

Click on "Add Webhook"

In "Payload URL", specify the URL of the server on which you want to enable the automated 'git pull', for example,

"https://yourserver.com/github/post_receive". We need to make sure the URL is https (secure), or we will get 302

Alternatively, Click on "Disable SSL verification"

For "Which events would you like to trigger this webhook?", select "Let me select individual events." and pick "Pull Request" and "Push"

Click on "Add webhook"

In "Recent Deliveries", verify that you are getting the right response and it is Green.

Webhook Post request triggers the following commands on your server,

Set up www-data group permission on Apache server

```
sudo apt-get install members

members www-data

adduser username www-data

chown www-data:www-data -R username

cp -R /home/username/.ssh /var/www/.ssh

chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www/.ssh

ls -la /var/www/.ssh

sudo chmod g+w .git -R
```